# Is this rule for graph isomorphism true?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true that two graphs are isomorphic if they:

> - Have the same number of vertices;
> - Have the same degree for each vertex, that is a graph with degrees $(2,3,2,3)$ would be the same as a graph with degrees $(2,2,3,3)$.
> - Have no loops;
> - Are connected.

I've made a few tests and this seems to be true. But I don't know how to prove it and hence am not completely sure about it.

Comment: no: `o-o+o-o` `o-o-o+o`

Comment: @JanDvorak What is this notation? I presume that the `o` is a vertex, but am in doubt about `-` and `+`.

Comment: `-` are edges, and `+` represents three vertices and four edges. Unfortunately, it's hard to draw a branching structure in ASCII

Comment: another example, from chemistry: 2-methyl-pentene (isohexane) and 3-methyl-pentene (with the methyl group sitting in the middle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is false.  The Wikipedia article on [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29#Degree_sequence) has a counterexample with 8 vertices:

[image: counterexample]

The two graphs are loopless and connected, and each has 3 vertices of degree 1, 4 vertices of degree 2, and 1 vertex of degree 3.  A similar example has 6 vertices. (just delete two of the order-2 vertices in each graph.)

(An earlier post by Alexander Gruber points at this paper, [“Trees
with
the
same
degree
sequence
and
path
numbers”](http://webbox.lafayette.edu/~gordong/pubs/oldtree.pdf) which is relavant here.)

Addendum: The minimal counterexample has only 5 vertices and 5 edges:

[image: minimal counterexample]

Because it's so small, it can be found by hand in a few minutes by simply enumerating all graphs.  This suggests that next time you have a conjecture, you might do well to try checking it for small graphs.  If you haven't previously tried to draw all the small graphs, this suggests that learning to do that would be a good investment of effort.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true.  More generally, there is no known list of graph properties that can be checked to ensure the two given graphs are isomorphic.